# In Electron, how can I open a window that isn't a BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron

In an Electron application, I'm interested in opening a window that is rendered by SDL, not Chromium's renderer. The only way to open a window that I can find is the `BrowserWindow` class. Is there any way to do this? Or will I need to use something like CEF instead?

I'm comfortable writing Node C++ AddOns or patching electron, but am not sure how to approach here.

Comment: It think creating a child process to open a SDL window would work.

Comment: @Sajin thanks, i'll try that and see if I can get something to work